# Sandbox paypal using Singapore Address

Tags: paypal, sandbox

I have created paypal sandbox account, but I need Singapore address.
When i create new account, there is no option for Singapore. 
I need to test my express checkout using Singapore address.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually create an account in Singapore by logging in to https://developer.paypal.com, and navigating to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/
Once there, click 'Sign up' and select 'Singapore' from the list.

Note: due to a defect on our end this account may not show up in the 'Sandbox accounts' list on https://developer.paypal.com/ at the moment. We're fixing this as we speak, but you will be able to use your newly created account just fine in the meantime.

Comment: Yes, this is the solution.
Before it, I think we cannot create sandbox for others country.
We can create sandbox paypal directly on https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/ 
So, we can choose Singapore, Indonesia etc.

Thnaks Robert

Comment: That's right - we're expanding the list of available countries in the automated creation form as we speak, so it should become easier over time.